# Converting ICONs in WPF to drawings

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

I have a GUI that uses a treeview which renders data objects into rows, including icons to denote object type etc for each row. Im noticing that the addition of the icon files into each row slows down the load and render a lot so Im toying with the idea of rewriting the icons as drawings. Ive done one proof of concept and mimicked an icon with the following

```
<Border Width="15" Height="15" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" Background="#22bb22" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path StrokeThickness="1.5" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" Data="M 2,4 C 2,4 10,4 9,12 M 2,7 C 2,7 7,7 6,12 M 2,10.5 L 4,10.5"/>
        </Border>
```

However I can't see how to include this as a static resource in my XAML. I want to load this drawing once and to re-use it throughout the application without having to redraw each time. Ive done something similar with images, creating a resource dictionary, then having a StaticResourceExtension class to look up via a key in that dictionary to find the image in the cache, and bind that to the source of the image tag. eg

```
<Image Source="{y:ImageStaticResource {Binding IconString}}" Margin="0,0,0,0"></Image>
```

ImageStaticResource is my custom class, and the IconString property of the datacontext is the key that looks up in the dictionary, which returns a string of the location of the image. This works and works very well. But I want to do something similar with these drawings but cant quite figure out how. Ive created a new Static Resource extension that does exactly the same but loads a different resource dictionary, the first entry of which is as follows

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                     
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

        <Border x:Key="Default" Width="15" Height="15" BorderThickness="0"></Border>

        <Border x:Key="..\Resources\Images\AccountOnly.ico" Width="15" Height="15" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="4,4,4,4" Background="#22bb22" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Path StrokeThickness="1.5" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" Data="M 2,4 C 2,4 10,4 9,12 M 2,7 C 2,7 7,7 6,12 M 2,10.5 L 4,10.5"/>
        </Border>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

So I am hoping to look up this bordered drawing by key (as all icons can be represented by a border surrounding a drawing but cannot figure out what to do. Can anyone offer suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve the same visual result by filling a Rectangle control with a DrawingBrush that is defined as resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="SomeIcon" Stretch="None">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#22bb22">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,15,15" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M 2,4 C 2,4 10,4 9,12 M 2,7 C 2,7 7,7 6,12 M 2,10.5 L 4,10.5">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Thickness="1.5"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</Window.Resources>

...

<Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{StaticResource SomeIcon}"/>
```

Comment: Would this be a lot more intensive than the Path method? I originally opted for the non geometry approach to keep it lightweight as there could be up to 5000 of these icons displayed in the treeview control at one time. I was also toying with the idea of doing it as a datatemplate but not too sure what parent UI Control I could use to set the datatemplate on. I tried button, but I can only set the contenttemplate which is no good as you get the button surrounding it.

Comment: Just the opposite. It would be considerably less resource-intensive than the approach with one Border control for every icon. A DrawingBrush is lightweight compared to a Border control. In fact it's the most lightweight solution i can think of, except perhaps bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

To "place" your Border that is in Resources somewhere in the visual tree....use the ContentControl, or ContentPresenter...and reference your keyed resource.

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Default}"/>
```

or

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ..\Resources\Images\AccountOnly.ico}"/>
```

(note the key name you have used on your second Border is a little unconventional)

However, you'll run into a problem doing that once you try and use the Border more than once i.e. the "specified element is already the logical child of another element".

You can mark the Resource with `x:Shared="False"`, so that a new instance is created for each reference...but then you might be back to square one i.e. inefficient rendering.

You could alternatively consider creating your own `FrameworkElement` derived class tailored specifically to do the minimum required to render your "icon", and optimize any shared data.

Try and avoid any heavier-weight "Control" derived classes if possible if you don't need the flexibility of templates.

Comment: I might be able to leverage this. I thought about putting the whole border structure inside a datatemplate, putting all the data templates in a resource dictionary, using my StaticResourceExtension class to dynamically bind the Template property of some UI Object to the template matching the resource key linked to the dependency property on the data object. I tried this and it works, however I have only experimented using the Button UI object, setting the ContentTemplate which just puts the drawing inside a button. Whats a lightweight UI control I could use to bind a template to?